# How to extract metrics from Jenkins in excel?

Tags: jenkins, metrics

I want to extract the build metrics from Jenkins to an excel sheet.

Is there any plugins to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Global Build Stats Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=46336030). Based on the REST API, you can retrieve the build stats data.

Comment: do we have a way in Global Build Stats Plugin where we can directly export the metrics to Excel or is there any other way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve the Json format and use [Json to CSV](https://konklone.io/json/)

to download the CSV file.